# Strawberry Perl and lwp - download and save doesn't work

Tags: perl, download, lwp

This code worked with ActiveState Perl 5.10, but with Strawberry Perl 5.14 it fails.
It downloads and saves jpeg partially, only 4Kb or so from the beginning. And every time size of downloaded file differs.
Response is always "200 OK".
LWP version is 6.04

```
use 5.14.0;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Headers;

my $img = 'https://avoncontent6.com/assets/ru-ru/images/product/prod_5045704_1_613x613.jpg';

my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
my $hh = HTTP::Headers->new(
  'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0',
  'Accept' => 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language' => 'en-us,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.3',
  'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
  'Connection' => 'keep-alive',
);
$ua->default_headers( $hh );
$ua->cookie_jar({});
$ua->timeout(20);

$ua->get($img, ':content_file' => "jpg/1.jpg");
```

Headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 20:32:14 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "031dd727cfce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Content-Length: 149607
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Oct 2013 13:08:46 GMT
Client-Aborted: die
Client-Date: Tue, 03 Dec 2013 20:32:15 GMT
Client-Peer: 162.13.51.77:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=EssentialSSL CA
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=Free SSL/CN=avoncontent6.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: RC4-SHA
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
X-Died: read failed: Inappropriate I/O control operation at D:/perl/perl/vendor/lib/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 414.
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
```

Comment: What's `$response->status_line`? What happens if you remove the timeout?

Comment: status is "200 OK"

Removing timeout doesn't help, everything is the same :(

Comment: I thought it changed the status code when it encountered an error, so I didn't notice this before: `X-Died: read failed: Inappropriate I/O control operation`. No idea what that means, but there was an error reading from the socket.

Comment: Does it help to remove `Accept-Encoding` request header?

Comment: Removed accept-encoding header - still the same.
I also don't know nothing about X-Died header in answer. But with the same script working under freebsd perl 5.14 it all works like a charm. So it's something either in Strawberry or in libwww for Strawberry :(

Comment: No, it's the OS returning that.

Comment: Well, with ActiveState perl 5.10 it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Installed older version libwww-perl-5.837

Comment: Can you try the _newest_ libwww-perl? 6.04, which you had before, is not the newest one, and Changes lists some interesting fixes.

Comment: Nope, cpan said that 6.04 is the latest available for my setup :(

Comment: Then you should fix also something else. Does `reload index` within the CPAN shell help? Also consider to upgrade the `Net::HTTP` module.